# ITreeContentProvider - How to filter files while still showing parent folder?

Tags: java, eclipse, swt, filefilter

I am currently trying to implement a `SWT` `CheckBoxTreeViewer` for my project. However, I am currently running into some problems with the file filtering.

I want my tree to show all files in a directory (including subdirectories) with a specific file extension (such as "txt") as well as their parent folders.

For example:

```
parentA
   childA1.txt
   childA2.txt
parentB
   childB1.txt
```

However, I can't figure out a way how to do this. I've tried several ways of coding the `FileFilter` as follows:

```
class FileTreeContentProvider implements ITreeContentProvider {

      public Object[] getChildren(Object arg0) {
        return ((File) arg0).listFiles();
      }

      public Object getParent(Object arg0) {
        return ((File) arg0).getParentFile();       
      }

      public boolean hasChildren(Object arg0) {
        Object[] obj = getChildren(arg0);
        return obj == null ? false : obj.length > 0;
      }
...
```

1)

```
 ...
   public Object[] getElements(Object arg0) {
      IWorkspace workspace = ResourcesPlugin.getWorkspace();
      File workspaceDirectory = workspace.getRoot().getLocation().toFile();
      String[] extension = new String[] {"txt"};
      Collection<File> files = FileUtils.listFiles(workspaceDirectory, extension, true);
      File[] files2 = new File[files.size()];
      int i = 0;
      for(File file : files) {
         files2[i] = file;
         i++;
      }
      return files2;
   }
   ...
}
```

The problem with this is that it only shows the files with the file extension but not its parent directories.
For example:

```
childA1.txt
childA2.txt
childB1.txt
```

2)

```
...
   public Object[] getElements(Object arg0) {
      IWorkspace workspace = ResourcesPlugin.getWorkspace();
      File workspaceDirectory = workspace.getRoot().getLocation().toFile();
      return workspaceDirectory.listFiles(new FilenameFilter() {
         @Override
         public boolean accept(File workspaceDirectory, String name) {
            if (workspaceDirectory.getName().startsWith(".") {
               return false;
            }
            else {
               return true;
            }
         }
      });
   }
   ...
}
```

This snippet removes the folders starting with "." in the root directory, but does not remove the files starting with "." in the subdirectories. Therefore, I got something like this:

```
parentA
   .project
   .settings
   childA1.txt
   childA2.txt
...
```

Also, as it does not explicitly filter in just files ending in "txt", if I were to put other file types in the workspace folder I would also see those files in the tree which is not something I want.

Is there anyway to fix this? I am using Eclipse Mars 4.5.1.

Comment: You haven't shown us what you do in `getChildren`. `getElements` only applies to the top level of the tree.

Comment: Actually, that just solved my problem. I didn't realize that `getElements` was the top level of the tree. I added a `FileFilter` to `getChildren` and everything is fixed now. Thanks!